# Applying styles from CSS to newly appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I add an element to a parent div dynamically.

```
$('.some_div').append("<li class="hi">hey!</li>")
```

In my CSS,

```
.hi {
  color: white;
}
```

However, since `<li class="hi">` is dynamically added, it seems the styles defined in CSS are not applied to the element. So,

```
$('.some_div').append("<li class='hi'>hey!</li>")
$('li.hi').css({"color":"white"});
```

would actually do the trick, but it seems redundant to me as the style is already defined in CSS file. Is this the only way to do it?

**Update:**

```
$('.some_div').append('<li style="color:white" >hey!</li>')
```

The above will work, but since the style is already defined in a separate CSS file, it'd be still redundant. My question was if there is a way to avoid this redundancy.

in CSS,

```
.some_div > li {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: 30px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.hi {
  color: white;
}
```

All of this won't be applied when I add a new element via `($).append()`, so I am asking if there is a way to apply the styles that are already defined in a stylesheet, without having to re-defining them in a `css()` function.

Comment: Change the class name "hi" to 'hi'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape name of class here.

Change

```
$('.some_div').append("<li class="hi">hey!</li>");
```

to

```
$('.some_div').append("<li class='hi'>hey!</li>");
```

OR

```
$('.some_div').append("<li class=\"hi\">hey!</li>");
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/J44YX/)

Demo with style:

```
$('.some_div').append("<li style='color:green;'>hey!</li>");
```

OR

```
$('.some_div').append("<li>hey!</li>").find("li:last").css("color","yellow");
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/J44YX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your string concatenation could be the problem, since your string literal is enclosed within `""` any occurrence of `"` within the string has to be escaped

```
$('.some_div').append('<li class="hi">hey!</li>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/seZE4/)

Note: also note that `li` is a valid child for `ul` or `ol` elements, so the `some_div` must be either one of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.some_div').append('<li class="hi">hey!</li>')
```

If you want to apply specific css for this element

```
$('.some_div').append('<li style="color:white" >hey!</li>')
```

If you want to apply CSS based on class

```
$('.hi').css("color","white");
```